# PHP Soap calling Error

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I am trying to connect to webservice using SOAP / wsdl, but I constantly get the error. I am new in soap-api in php. I have a document of api detail, it shows:

```
public WSGetCalendarFareResponse GetCalendarFare(WSGetCalendarFareRequest calanderFareRequest)
```

I made my code accordingly but still found error/exception.  Please review my php code in following:

```
$wsdl = "http://api.abc.com/xyz/service.asmx?wsdl"; // This is a test Web Service URL
    $h = array();
    $opta["GetCalendarFare"]["request"]= array(
    "Origin"=>"DEL",
    "Destination"=>"IXR",
    "DepartureDate"=>"2015-05-01T00:00:00",
    "ReturnDate"=>"2015-05-01T00:00:00",
    "Type"=>"OneWay",
    "CabinClass"=>"All",
    "PreferredCarrier"=>"",
    "AdultCount"=>1,
    "ChildCount"=>1,
    "InfantCount"=>"0",
    "SeniorCount"=>"0",
    "PromotionalPlanType"=>"Normal",
    "IsDirectFlight"=>false
    );

    $client_header = new SoapHeader('http://192.168.0.0/TEST/BookingAPI','AuthenticationData',$hparams,false);
    $cliente = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => 0));
    $cliente->__setSoapHeaders(array($client_header));
    try{
    $h= (array)$cliente->__call('GetCalendarFare',$opta);
    }catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($e);
    }
```

When I execute my code, it returns following error:

```
"System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at BookingAPI.WSCalendarFareInput(WSGetCalendarFareRequest calanderFareRequest) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\api.tektravel.com\TboApi_V7\App_Code\Service.cs:line 4544
   at BookingAPI.GetCalendarFare(WSGetCalendarFareRequest calanderFareRequest) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\api.tektravel.com\TboApi_V7\App_Code\Service.cs:line 4360
```

Can anyone please suggest that where problem exists? It hit & try many times but couldn't get the error point.

Answer (score 1):

Can you debug the execution of your POST on the server side? It is heavy guessing from my side, but I assume that you do not set a mandatory value in the request, which the server needs to deserialize your object. Hence the *NullReferenceException*.

Comment: thankyou Seb. You are right , I made mistake in request. I have to set request value as following:  $opta["GetCalendarFare"]["calanderFareRequest"]= array();  Thanks for your comment.

Comment: It would be nice then, if you could mark my answer as correct or at least up-vote it to appreciate the hint. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Problem has resolved.

The Request array should be like this:

```
$opta["GetCalendarFare"]["calanderFareRequest"]= array(
    "Origin"=>"DEL",
    "Destination"=>"IXR",
    "DepartureDate"=>"2015-05-01T00:00:00",
    "ReturnDate"=>"2015-05-01T00:00:00",
    "Type"=>"OneWay",
    "CabinClass"=>"Economy",
    "PreferredCarrier"=>"",
    "AdultCount"=>1,
    "ChildCount"=>1,
    "InfantCount"=>"0",
    "SeniorCount"=>"0",
    "PromotionalPlanType"=>"Normal",
    "IsDirectFlight"=>false
    );
```